# Summing values in a nested dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I have a structure of nested dictionaries. When I access values for a key in the outermost dictionary, it returns the below.

```
print d['key1'].values()    

dict_values([{'4a3': 22, '4a1': 10, '3a1': 1}, {'4a3': 16, '4a1': 4, '3c1': 2}])
```

I would like to sum across each unique key within the above and then divide that by the total count for that key (in this case 55) so for the example above:

```
{'4a3': 0.69, '4a1': 0.25, '3a1': 0.02, '3ac': 0.04}
```

How can I go about this and in a cost-efficient way, as I have many keys in my dictionary, which will be summed onto the above?

Thanks!

Comment: so... each first level key has a list of dictionaries?

Comment: Do you just want this one `dict_values` averaged, or all of the keys in the dict? If the latter, please show the whole dict.. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @LucasWieloch that's correct

Comment: @ggorlen it's an average value

Comment: @ggorlen the decimals come from dividing by the total count for 'key1' which is 55

Comment: How do you get this total count from? Is it the length of the list for each first level key, or the sum of each unique key on the second level? that is confusing

Comment: by summing all of the counts for associated with keys within dict_values

Comment: @LucasWieloch the above can be treated as a dictionary in itself. I just need to know how to sum across it so values are summed for example (4a3: 22+16 = 38) and divided across the total for that dictionary (38/55 = 0.69)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `defaultdict` where the keys are the different keys in the list of dictionaries, and the values are their counts, also, using a total variable to store the total count:

```
vals = [{'4a3': 22, '4a1': 10, '3a1': 1}, {'4a3': 16, '4a1': 4, '3c1': 2}]

from collections import defaultdict

result = defaultdict(int)

total = 0

for d in vals:
  for k, v in d.items():
    result[k] += v
    total += v

for k in result:
  result[k] = round(result[k] / total, 2)

print(result)
```

Output:

```
defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'4a3': 0.69, '4a1': 0.25, '3a1': 0.02, '3c1': 0.04})
```

If you want a dict, you can either do:

```
result = dict(result)
```

Output:

```
{'4a3': 0.69, '4a1': 0.25, '3a1': 0.02, '3c1': 0.04}
```

Comment: Thank you! defaultdict is perfect for this task. I'll get my head around how to use it in the future

Answer (score 0):

I think this is it:

```
aggregate_dict = dict()
for el in d['key1']:
    for key, val in dict.iteritems():
        if aggregate_dict.has_key(key):
            aggregate_dict[key]+= val
        else:
            aggregate_dict[key] = val

total_count = sum(aggregate_dict.values())

result = { key : round(float(val)/total_count, 2) for key, val in aggregate_dict.iteritems() }
```

I only have python 2.7 right now, I think you don't need to use `float(val)` in python3 (I think you also need to change `iteritems` to `items`)